# Recursively search for where new item goes inside sorted list?

Tags: java, recursion, sortedlist

I'm trying to implement a search method, which returns a index of a object where it should be inserted in a sorted list, recursively.

Here is my attempt.

```
 //listSize is the number of elements inside the sorted list 
 //sortedList is the actual structure holding the values
 // Note: the parameter Value is comparable.  
 public int search(T value,int index){

    if(listSize == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if(index > listSize){
        return listSize+1; //add at the end
    }
    if(value.compareTo(sortedList[index]) > 0 && value.compareTo(sortedList[index+1]) < 0){
        //value is less 
        return index+1;
    }else if(value.compareTo(sortedList[index]) == 0){
        //both are same
        return index+1;
    }
    return search(value,index++);
}
```

For some reason I seem to be getting a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Even if you fix the error properly identified by templatetypedef, you're still going to have the problem that you're using a stack frame per element in the list, so you'll still encounter the problem whenever your list is larger than a few thousand elements. Seeing how the list is, indeed, sorted, you will probably want to implement a binary search instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're saying

```
return search(value,index++);
```

The effect of `index++` is "increment index, then hand back the value that `index` used to have."  This means that the value of `index` passed into the recursive call will be the same as in the original call.  I think you want to change this to read

```
return search(value, index + 1);
```

Which more correctly passes the value of `index + 1` into `search`.

There may be other errors here, but this certainly is going to cause problems.  Try changing this and see what happens.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `++index` should do the same.

Comment: LOL cant believe i made that mistake!

Comment: @Nishant- That's true, but since `index` is a local variable that's about to go out of scope I don't see any reason to use `++index` here.  The side-effect is misleading and a minor tweak to the code (going back to `index++`) breaks it.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget the case, that you have to insert *before* index? If value < sortedList[index] your method will call itself recursively endlessly...

**EDIT**:

If you fix your "index++" bug, you should now see the incorrect behavior that values that are supposed to be inserted at the beginning of the list, would instead be appended.